# Conditional Sum in R from data frame

Tags: r

| make | model year | wt doors | protection | size | dp | hic | chest.decel | l.leg | r. leg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acura | Integra RS | 90 | Motorized belts | lt | Driver | 585 | NA | 1545 | 1301 |
| ... | ... | ... | .... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have this dataframe above and I would like to find the sum of the values in the hic column that are greater than 800. I have tried this line of code

```
sum(databank$hic>800)
```

But I am getting back

```
NA
```

Answer (score 0):

There are missing values in your data.frame, use:

```
sum(databank$hic>800,na.rm = TRUE)
```

Since many R functions return `NA` by default, if a `NA` is present.